# Is it possible to create a multiprocess UI in .net?

Tags: .net

Is it possible to create a windows application in .net that is similar to chrome.

By this I mean that each screen/tab is a process.

Comment: If you mean multiple tabs each with their own browser, for example, then yes this is possible.

Comment: @MrWednesday  no I mean each form/control (winform or wpf) is hosted in its own process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically there is no magic in what chrome dose.

You need a host process which provides the basic UI. This host process then launches a child process for each separated context you what to have (like the pages in chrome). Now you need a way to let thees child process communicate with the host. This can be done with named pipes on windows. The host creates a pipe and can handle that pipes name to the child via process argument. (If you open Process Explorer and look at a child process of chrome, you will see an argument like this --channel=6831.059FF640.845232221)

Now you add a window to each child process which has no borders (only plain content). The host now needs to send all windows changes to that child. So if the host moves, the child needs to correct its position in real time too. If the host gets minimized, the child needs also to get minimized etc. If the context is switched, one child windows gets invisible and the one appears.

If that child dies, you only need to create a new one, restore its state and you are done.

An alternative for the scenario of chrome is to send all mouse and keyboard interactions within the content to that child process, then do all processing and calculation in that child process and send the rending information back (over the named pipe) to the host which then dose the rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You can create each of your form using a `Thread` and that form will be hold by that thread. But note you cannot be able to access other forms control.

But if you want to have a complete Chrome like application, you have to develop your application using Visual C++

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specific mechanism that chrome uses. However, I do know that you can re-parent a HWND into another process. In fact, I'd bet good money that any technique that chrome uses can be duplicated in .Net with a bit of P/Invoke.